# Multi column constraint in web2py

Tags: web2py

I am trying to use the method posted by [Anthony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054665/multi-column-unique-constraint-with-web2py)

```
db.define_table('ts_customer',
            Field('customer_name', 'string', length=80, required=True, unique=True))

db.define_table('ts_mileage_rate',
            Field('customer_id', 'reference ts_customer', required=True, notnull=True),
            Field('mileage_rate_year', 'integer', required=True, notnull=True,
                  requires=IS_NOT_IN_DB(
                      db(db.ts_mileage_rate.customer_id == request.vars.customer_id),
                      'ts_mileage_rate.mileage_rate_year')
            ))
```

I get the following error:

type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> 'DAL' object has no attribute 'ts_mileage_rate'

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You have `db.ts_mileage_rate.customer_id` within the definition of the `ts_mileage_rate` table, so the table doesn't yet exist. Instead, define the `requires` attribute after the table definition:

```
db.ts_mileage_rate.mileage_rate_year.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(
    db(db.ts_mileage_rate.customer_id == request.vars.customer_id),
    'ts_mileage_rate.mileage_rate_year')
```